# Wifi connection suffers severely from external hard drive use

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, external-hard-drive, connection

My computer's wifi is usually quite fast and can easily serve my internet connection (160 Mbit/s down, 10 Mbit/s up) to my computer. However, when I connect an external hard drive, my internet connection gets cripplingly slow and horribly unreliable. Sometimes no data moves at all for minutes, sometimes data occasionally moves but it takes half a minute for a single letter to be transmitted to an SSH instance and the most simple web pages fail to load. I have a feeling that it's worse when I copy data between different external hard drives but I have yet to objectively asses that. Weirdly enough, **the connection stays slow and unreliable until reboot even after the copying process has finished and I have detached the external hard drive.**

My wifi connection is provided via the onboard wifi of my motherboard (`MSI B450 Gaming Pro Carbon AC`). The wifi router is just 3 m and a brick wall away.

Other devices in the same wifi network are unaffected.

The problem occurs with all 3 external hard drives I currently use on this computer. They're all connected via USB 3.0.

The computer is running Kubuntu 18.04 (kernel `4.15.0-58-generic`). The network indicator does not indicate that the connection drops. The connection isn't always bad, only most of the time, even though I'm continuously pulling data from an external hard drive or writing data to it.

What could be the cause of this problem? How can it be solved (except by using a proper CAT 5 which would be very inconvenient)?

Comment: Two testing approaches:  1) Cover the external hard drives with heavy duty aluminum foil, and tuck one end of the foil into the case to ground it. 2) Use an Android app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.javali.wifisnr&hl=en_US to waith for an increase in noise when attaching and using an external drive.

Comment: @K7AAY I don't have aluminum foil on hand but I doubt it makes a difference after the detail I noticed by now and have added to the question. Thus far, I had always shut down my computer after the copying process had finished as copying some data was the last thing I did the past few days. However, I installed the app you linked to yesterday and was completely unable to detect proximity to my computer or the external hard drive using it. There just doesn't seem to be any correlation between what the app shows and how close I am to my computer or the external hard drive.